# How to pass a string as variable to felm regression

Tags: r, formula

This works:

```
felm(y ~ x1 + x2  | fe1 + fe2 | 0 | , data = data)
```

I want:

```
fixedeffects = "fe1 + fe2"
felm(y ~ x1 + x2  | fixedeffects | 0 | , data = data)
```

I tried:

```
 fixedeffects = "fe1 + fe2"
eval(bquote(felm(y ~ x1 + x2  | .(fixedeffects) | 0 | , data = data)))
```

but this only works if `fixedeffects` is just one variable

Answer (score 4):

Untested, but probably

```
form <- as.formula(sprintf("y ~ x1 + x2 | %s | 0 |",
                   fixedeffects))
felm(form , data = data)
```

If you had `fixedeffects` stored as a vector of individual terms you could use `paste(fixedeffects, collapse="+")` to combine them.

It's not really needed in this case, but `reformulate()` is useful for these cases (really just a bit of sugar):

```
form <- reformulate(
  sprintf("~ x1 + x2 | %s | 0 |", fixedeffects),
  response="y")
```

the default behaviour of `reformulate()` is to concatenate a vector of terms with `+`, which isn't so useful here (hence we only pass it a single term).

Answer (score 1):

If you have many dependent variables, many fixed effects, and possibly multiway clustered errors, all stored in vectors, you can paste the whole formula.

A working example:

```
library(plm)
library(lfe)

data("Gasoline", package = "plm")

rhs <- c("lincomep", "lrpmg" )
fe <- c("country", "year")

myf <- function(x)paste(x, collapse = "+")

f <- as.formula(paste(
                      "lgaspcar ~ ",
                      myf(rhs),
                      "|",
                      myf(fe) ))

lm <- felm(f, d=Gasoline) 
summary(lm)
```

Also, note that `| 0 |` for "no instruments" is not required, if dont have clustered errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly strings, but likely useful in your purpose, package [`fixest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/index.html) offers formula macros. You should be able to do what you want with them.

Use `setFixest_fml` to set the macros and `xpd` to use them.

Here's an example:

```
# A) Set the macros (macros vars. must start with two dots)
setFixest_fml(..fe = ~ fe1 + fe2)

# B) use them with xpd
xpd(y ~ x1 + x2 | ..fe)
#> y ~ x1 + x2 | fe1 + fe2 

# You can also change the macro variables on the fly:
fml = y ~ x1 + x2 | ..fe
xpd(fml, ..fe = ~ fe1)
#> y ~ x1 + x2 | fe1
xpd(fml, ..fe = ~ fe1 + fe2 + fe3)
#> y ~ x1 + x2 | fe1 + fe2 + fe3
```

If you use using `fixest` for fixed-effect estimations (which is the purpose of the package), then macros are automatically expanded (no need of `xpd`):

```
library(fixest)
data(airquality)
setFixest_fml(..ctrl = ~ Temp + Day,
              ..ctrl_long = ~ poly(Temp, 2) + poly(Day, 2),
              ..fe = ~ Month)

# You can use the macros without xpd() in fixest estimations
a <- feols(Ozone ~ Wind + ..ctrl |..fe, airquality)
b <- feols(Ozone ~ Wind + ..ctrl_long | ..fe, airquality)
etable(a, b)
#>                                     a                b
#> Wind                  -2.796* (1.289)  -2.665. (1.468)
#> Temp                 2.16*** (0.1805)                 
#> Day                   0.2579 (0.2165)                 
#> poly(Temp,2)1                         212.3*** (17.62)
#> poly(Temp,2)2                         81.46*** (23.94)
#> poly(Day,2)1                             24.42 (17.55)
#> poly(Day,2)2                             16.25 (43.28)
#> Fixed-Effects:       ---------------- ----------------
#> Month                             Yes              Yes
#> ___________________  ________________ ________________
#> Observations                      116              116
#> S.E. type: Clustered        by: Month        by: Month
#> R2                            0.60607           0.6385
#> Within R2                      0.4849           0.5273
```

Some general information on `fixest` can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/fixest_walkthrough.html).